# What is the difference between Stateless class with empty constructor and Static class?

Tags: php, oop, static-methods, stateless

Assuming that I have to create a class that takes some text do some processing and return it ... with no dependency and it's a stateless class..

I'd like to know would be better to create a stateless class without constructor or just create a static class (in php it's just Static methods)

class like this:

```
class ClassName
{
    public function processText($text)
    {
         // Some code
         $text = $this->moreProcessing($text);
         return $text;
    }

    protected function moreProcessing($text)
    {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
class ClassName
{
    public static function processText($text)
    {
         // Some code
         $text = static::moreProcessing($text);
         return $text;
    }

    protected static function moreProcessing($text)
    {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

**I Know that dependency injection into the class where these classes are used would be better** but assume that I just won't have dependency injection..

My question is mainly would it be better to create static class for the simple example above?

Comment: The question is rather, why you would have a class without any state. That's not a class, it's a function container...

Comment: Must read : http://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html

Comment: What is the difference between `protected static function` and `protected function`? Well, there's no polymorphic behavior in static methods and that's it

Comment: @EricShaefer you are right, it's just that I don't want to include methods that are doing nothing but cleaning text in a class mainly responsible for DB operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically you will see no difference whatsoever.

It's only in the syntax, and the ability of a constructor to perform stuff automatically, though you still have to create instances to invoke the constructor, which in this case is not far off calling some equivalent `static` member function.

However, non-`static` member functions are *supposed* to affect internal state so, if you have no state, `static` member functions seem more conventional, and will be slightly less surprising to users of the class.

The best approach, though, is to stick your functions in a namespace. Classes are for data and functions operating on that data... even `static` ones.

Comment: There's no difference between global state and `Class::functionNamspace`

Comment: @djay: The. OP. Has. No. State.